# Slow Cheetah transform failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, slowcheetah

In Visual Studio 2012 I have Slow Cheetah version 2.5.10 installed.  When building an app that uses Slow Cheetah, the build fails with the following error:

> Error 1   The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task could not be loaded
>   from the assembly
>   C:\Users\MyActiveDirectoryAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.10\SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Users\MyActiveDirectoryAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.10\SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  C:\Users\MyActiveDirectoryAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v1\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets

When navigating to this directory, I can see the Slow Cheetah files, but the SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll file is missing.

C:\Users\MyActiveDirectoryAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.10\

To triage this, I've:

1. Rebooted
2. Un-installed and re-installed Slow Cheetah
3. Clean and rebuild

None of the above fixed the problem.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936476/the-slowcheetah-xdt-transformxml-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in one of the [Q & A's](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Reviews/5) (by zendu)

> Copy the files from
>
> %APPDATA%..\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v1.
>
> to
>
> %APPDATA%..\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v2.5.10.
>
> List of files:
> Install-Manifest.xml
> Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll
> SlowCheetah.Tasks.dll
> SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets
> SlowCheetah.Xdt.dll

[Source](http://techblog.lbigroup.be/2013/11/08/slowcheetah-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/)

Also see this related question
[The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task could not be loaded from the assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936476/the-slowcheetah-xdt-transformxml-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly)

Comment: Thanks @Amitd.  The link you provided leads to this, which actually solved my problem.  https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/114

Comment: Short answer:  If you delete the userDir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah\v1 directory and the v2.5.10 directory, then rebuild, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2010. I just install the SlowCheetah nuget package (install-package SlowCheetah) and after that the build succeed. The nuget package set up correctly the slowcheetah task in your solution.

[SlowCheetah nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah)