# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API - SlowCheetah

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, slowcheetah

**Solution**
That one line in .csproj file solved the problem.

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" />
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------**

How could I use SlowCheetah at an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API ?

I have the following settings in my `.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="Transform" BeforeTargets="_TransformAppSettings;_TransformWebConfig">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ScFilesToTransform Remove="@(ScFilesToTransform)" />
      <ScWapPubProfileFullPath Include="$(WebPublishProfileFile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ScPubProfile Condition="'$(ScPubProfile)' == '' and '@(ScWapPubProfileFullPath)' != ''">%(ScWapPubProfileFullPath.Filename)</ScPubProfile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ScFilesToTransform Include="@(None);@(Content);@(Resource);@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition=" '%(TransformOnBuild)' == 'true' ">
        <SourceFile>%(FullPath)</SourceFile>
        <TransformFile>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).$(Configuration)%(Extension)</TransformFile>
        <DestinationFile>$(OutDir)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationFile>
        <DestinationFile Condition="'%(Link)' != ''">$(OutDir)%(Link)</DestinationFile>
        <PublishDestinationFile>$(PublishDir)\%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</PublishDestinationFile>
        <PublishDestinationFile Condition="'%(Link)' != ''">$(PublishDir)\%(Link)</PublishDestinationFile>
        <PublishTransformFile>%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).$(ScPubProfile)%(Extension)</PublishTransformFile>
      </ScFilesToTransform>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <_ScPublishDirsToCreate Include="@(ScFilesToTransform -> '%(PublishDestinationFile)')" Condition="Exists('%(TransformFile)') or Exists('%(PublishTransformFile)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <MakeDir Directories="@(_ScPublishDirsToCreate->'%(RelativeDir)')" Condition=" !Exists('%(RelativeDir)') " />
    <SlowCheetah.TransformTask Condition="Exists('%(TransformFile)')" Destination="%(PublishDestinationFile)" Source="@(ScFilesToTransform->'%(SourceFile)')" Transform="%(TransformFile)" />
    <SlowCheetah.TransformTask Condition=" Exists('%(PublishTransformFile)') and '$(ScPubProfile)'!='' and '$(ScPubProfile)' != '$(Configuration)'" Destination="%(PublishDestinationFile)" Source="@(ScFilesToTransform->'%(PublishDestinationFile)')" Transform="%(PublishTransformFile)" />
  </Target>
```

The error that I get:

> The "SlowCheetah.TransformTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:...\Api\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:...\Api\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
> Calendar.Api  C:...\Api\Calendar.Api.csproj

Comment: The error seems to indicate that the SlowCheetah dll is not accessible at the reported path. Check the path where SlowCheetah is being loaded from is correct.

Comment: See here for possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936476/the-slowcheetah-xdt-transformxml-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly

Comment: I update my question, because i solved it.

Comment: You should really add an answer with the detail of what fixed it for you (you can accept it too) rather than add the solution in the question.

Comment: Do you really need SlowCheetah?  It was a fudge for .net framework 4.5+ and isn't how .NET Core apps should be written.

Comment: Yes, i updated an application from .net framework to .net core, and we have a lot of .config file and etc... :/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
That one line in .csproj file solved the problem.

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" />
```